# IIS7 / MVC4 Routing: Run different routes in separate app pools?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, application-pool

Can I configure IIS7 to run the actions of two separate controllers under two separate routes in different app pools?

Using old .svc web services, I could separate service calls by having a separate .svc file under a particular directory, whereby I could make the directory a Virtual Directory allowing me to run the service as a different identity (or with different authentication settings).  This gave me the ability to have a single code base deployed to separate web structure locations.

I now have a single MVC (/WebApi) application, with multiple service APIs.  Some of these service calls have to be run in a different app pool from the rest for security purposes.

Despite being separate service methods on separate routes within the application, IIS only sees it as a single application, and (apparently) has no way to map the virtual routes within MVC to Virtual Directory settings.

Creating a separate MVC application and hosting it in a Virtual Directory under the root site causes issues around web.config inheritance, which again I haven't found a way around.

Having said all this, my knowledge of IIS7 is very limited, and googling just brings up posts based on keywors that don't cover this particular scenario.

Would appreciate any help.

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: If it's an option: Hosting multiple MVC applications, each in its own virtual directory, with no web.config in the root site, works fine.

Comment: @phil We are trying to do this in my app, because we occasionally need to restart the app pool due to a 3rd party component that gets corrupted. By making a certain route use a different app pool, we hope to be able to cycle just that component without affecting the rest of the system

Answer (score 0):

Web.config is inherited in directories and virtual directories, but not across applications.  Please make sure your subdirectory is set up as an application (right click on parent, select add application or right click on sub directory and select "convert to application").  At this point each application has it's own web.config file.